# Positioning Text in C# Console

Tags: c#, console-application

I've been trying to work on a program that renders text into a certain area on the command line. I have no idea how to do this. ***Basically, the user is going to choose a width and a height. I was wanting to use that data to put the text in a certain area of the screen.*** If you know how to do this please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick where the next Console.Write command writes to, by setting the cursor position via the [Console.SetCursorPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setcursorposition?view=net-5.0#System_Console_SetCursorPosition_System_Int32_System_Int32_) method.